# Fragment not getting accessibility focus after replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, accessibility

I have an activity that has a fragment. That fragment gets the accessibility  focus correctly. But when a replace the first fragment with another one, the second one is not getting the focuse automatically, I have to touch the fragment to get the focus.

This is the way a do the replace:

```
val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, myFragment)
fragmentTransaction.commit()
container.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
```

I try to add the `android:importantForAccessibility` and the `android:clickable="true"` to the second fragment (the one that is not getting accessibility focus)

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:importantForAccessibility="yes">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

I also try to use the add fragment instead of replace with the same result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution - you can simply notify a user about screen change. If your fragment contains a toolbar, then you can set it focused while fragment is being displayed. or you could focus on the first/main reasonable element. In this way, It will announce a new screen to the user and it will be more helpful to users.

```
toolbar.requestFocus()
toolbar.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please use below code** 
In first fragment before you do the fragment transaction.

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, null, false);
rootView.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Is not working as expected, because the content of the first fragment is not accessible anymore.

Comment: Please use  rootView.setImportantForAccessibility()  code just before replacing the  fragment

Comment: But rootView.setImportantForAccessibility() should be done in the onCreateView method of the fragment and the onCreateView is called after the replacing.

Comment: you can declare root view globally and call rootView.setImportantForAccessibility()  just before the  replacing the fragment

Comment: this solution does not help

Answer (score 0):

You can perform accessibility action in fragment onActivityCreated method like below

```
getParentActivity().getToolbar().
          performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null);
```